# Where can I ask about wheeled vehicle design solutions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to ask about design of a military wheeled vehicle: why it was done that way and not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your question is a bit vague (but maybe that was intentional). If you can supply more details (photos etc.) it might be welcomed by [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/). They have quite a few questions about [automotive engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automotive-engineering) and I suspect your question might fit under that umbrella. For example, this question about military vehicle design: [What is the rationale for a 6x6 truck chassis with 2 axles front vs. 6x6 chassis with 2 axles rear?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/31600/6767)

As always, please check their [Help Center](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking.